# Trying to write strcmp() function

Tags: c

I am trying  to write the strcmp() function. This code seems to work properly for dissimilar strings, however when strings are same it does not return 0, instead it returns 83.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int xstrcmp(char *, char*);
int main() {
    int i;
    char string1[]="SUNDAY";
    char string2[]="SUNDAY";
    i=xstrcmp(string1,string2);
    printf("\n %d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
int xstrcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
   while(*s1-*s2==0)
    {
        *s1++;
        *s2++;
    }
   return(*s1-*s2);
}
```

Comment: What do expect `*s1++` to do? How is it different from `s1++` ?

Comment: With a while that goes on as long as the characters are equal, how will this function ever return zero?

Answer (score 2):

For two identical strings your `while` loop will go on after the strings have ended and read some data after the strings. That's undefined behavior. Your program may read some data unrelated to the string. Or it may crash due to access violation. In any case your function can never return zero as the `while` will go on as long as `*s1` equals `*s2`. Solution: You need to check for "end-of-string", i.e. like `*s1 == '\0'`.

The expression `*s1++` reads the character that `s1` points to and leaves `s1` incremented. However, since you don't use the read character there is no reason to do the read. Just do `s1++` or `++s1`.

`*s1-*s2==0` is not wrong but it seems a strange way of doing `*s1==*s2`.

You can rewrite it like:

```
while(*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2)
{
    ++s1;
    ++s2;
}
return(*s1-*s2);
```

However, it's sufficient to check for "end-of-string" for one of the strings so you can even do:

```
while(*s1 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2)
{
    ++s1;
    ++s2;
}
return(*s1-*s2);
```

Comment: Actually, `*s1-*s2==0` _might_ be wrong: if `char` is signed, it may result in UB if the arithmetic overflows.  Similarly, `return *s1 - *s2;` should be replaced with `return (s2 < s1) - (s1 < s2);` to avoid the same UB.

Comment: @TobySpeight Actually not. Integer promotion makes it well defined.

Comment: Only on platforms where `int` is larger than `char` (yes, pretty much every system you're likely to work on, but still possibly UB).

Answer (score 1):

For a start, a proper signature for a `strcmp`-like function would be:

```
int xstrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

The function shouldn't have any side effects observable by the caller. You shouldn't be modifying what is pointed to by any of the pointers.

You also don't have a proper terminating condition for the loop. A `for` loop without a body would be sufficient:

```
for (; *s1 && *s1 == *s2; s1++, s2++);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to check if the strings ended.

```
int xstrcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
   while(*s1-*s2==0 && *s1!=0) // add end of string check
    {
        *s1++;
        *s2++;
    }
   return(*s1-*s2);
}
```

Also note that dereferencing `s1` and `s2` (using `*`) in the loop is meaningless (not harmful though).

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 6 issues:

- **Key problem**: `while(*s1-*s2==0)` does not terminate the loop when both strings reach the *null character* at the same time.
- **Subtle Bug**: `*s1-*s2` is the wrong difference when one of the characters is negative as *string* operations, to be like those in `<string.h>`, should treat the values as if they were *unsigned* even when `char` is *signed*. "For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char`" C23dr § 7.26.1 4.  This is important to sort strings consistently across platforms.
- Function more useful when the arguments are allowed to point to `const` strings.  This matches `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);`.
- Rare: On select systems, where `char` is as wide as `int`, `*s1-*s2` may overflow causing *undefined behavior* (UB).  Easily avoided with `(*us1 > *us2) - (*us1 < *us2)` which works on all systems and many compilers recognized this idiom and emit efficient code.
- Pedantic: On obsolete systems with a *signed char* that is not 2's compliment, `*s1-*s2` is the wrong compare as -0 should be considered distinct from +0.
- Dereferencing not needed in `*s1++`.  Simply increment the pointer `s1++`.

Putting that together:

```
int xstrcmp_alt(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  const unsigned char *us1 = (const unsigned char *) s1;
  const unsigned char *us2 = (const unsigned char *) s2;

  // First check if characters are the same, 
  //   its the more likely than the 2nd test to fail.
  // Then check if one of them in a not a null character.
  while(*us1 == *us2 && *us1) {
    us1++;
    us2++;
  }
  return (*us1 > *us2) - (*us1 < *us2);
}
```